# How to share folders over the network in Xubuntu 18.04?

Tags: networking, xubuntu, samba, xfce

How to share folders over the network in Xubuntu 18.04?
I work on Xubuntu laptop, others have installed Windows 7 and 10 on their machines.

Comment: Edit your original post and add the ouptut of the following commands: "testparm -s" and "net usershare info --long". Are the clients to this machine running Windows ( and if so which versions ) or are they running Linux or MacOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1670223

1. `sudo apt install samba system-config-samba`
2. Run system-config-samba - just type `sudo system-config-samba` in terminal.
3. After running `sudo system-config-samba` I got an error "'SystemError: could not open configuration file /etc/libuser.conf: No such file or directory". Simple solution is `sudo touch /etc/libuser.conf` found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/428226/system-config-samba-crash-with-could-not-open-configuration-file-etc-libuser-c)
4. Run `sudo system-config-samba` again.
5. Create the share (choose File > Add Share, or click the plus icon):

   - Directory = select directory to share
   - Share name = share name
   - Description = description
   - Writable = to allow users to write to directory
   - Visible = to make the share visible while browsing
   - Access tab = select who should have access to the share
6. In Thunar, access "Network" or "Browse Network" (on the bottom left)

I have to think a moment about my question, if I should edit it to be more precise and concrete.

Comment: Finally, this worked for me. I've been having trouble transferring files to/from a new Win 10 laptop that replaced a Win 7 unit that died (but there was no trouble with sharing a folder or two under "workgroup" which was removed in Win 10! New Laptop could only see my printer, no matter all the terminal commands I've tried and configuration files i've messed with in Xubuntu. Why this isn't installed by default i'll never know.

Answer (score 3):

**To share a folder in Samba**

- Add User `sudo adduser <user-name>`
- create password `sudo smbpasswd -a <user-name>`
- Create share:
  `sudo -H gedit /etc/samba/smb.conf`

Add the following to the end of smb.conf file

```
[<folder-name]
    path = /path/to/folder
    writeable = yes
    browseable = yes
    guest ok = no
```

close the file and run:

```
sudo systemctl restart smbd nmbd
```

Done.