# Network sharing from Xubuntu 18.04 to Windows 10 fails, (system-config-samba crashes)

Tags: xubuntu, samba, shared-folders

**Specs:**

Computer 01: Xubuntu 18.04, with default out of the box samba components.

Computer 02: Windows 10.

Network Topology: Both computers are ethernet connected to a Modem/Router

**Description of the problem:**

1. Windows 10 can not see anything being shared from Xubuntu 18.04, not even a domain.
2. The system-config-samba command crashes with the following error message:

Command:

`sudo -H system-config-samba`

Output:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/sbin/system-config-samba", line 45, in <module>
    mainWindow.MainWindow(debug_flag)
  File "/usr/share/system-config-samba/mainWindow.py", line 82, in __init__
    self.samba_data = sambaParser.SambaParser(self)
  File "/usr/share/system-config-samba/sambaParser.py", line 185, in __init__
    self.parseFile ()
  File "/usr/share/system-config-samba/sambaParser.py", line 228, in parseFile
    section = SambaSection (token.value)
  File "/usr/share/system-config-samba/sambaParser.py", line 49, in __init__
    raise Error ("section %s already defined" % (name))
NameError: global name 'Error' is not defined`

**Here are the things I've tried:**

1. Clean install of Xubuntu 18.04, then clean install of samba and its dependencies.
2. Using the default samba install to try and configure a connection for Windows 10 to see.
3. [AskUbuntu: samba sharing service not installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1131770/xubuntu-bugs-samba-sharing-services-not-installed)
4. [AskUbuntu: How do I share folders in Xubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/321418/how-do-i-share-folders-in-xubuntu)
5. [AskUbuntu: share folders over the network in Xubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1130859/how-to-share-folders-over-the-network-in-xubuntu-18-04)

**Question/Request:**

I desperately need this to get this functional as soon as possible to access the files I need for my work (these files are not on the same drive as the OS).

Any help to find a workaround or to get this functioning is what I'm after here.

I'm also not opposed to installing a different Linux distribution as long as it has a stable and functioning network sharing component out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[1] If you kept your Win10 machine up-to-date it will never be able to "discover" any Linux samba server using NetBIOS because Win10 effectively turns it off by disabling client side SMB1.

[2] I would suggest not trying to get system-config-samba to work. It's been removed from the repositories in later releases.

[3] I would start simple - In this example I will use my name as yours so make appropriate adjustments:

Create a guest accessible share to your Public folder by editing `/etc/samba/smb.conf` and at the bottom of the file add this:

```
[Public]
path = /home/morbius/Public
read only = No
guest ok = yes
force user = morbius
```

Then restart smbd: `sudo service smbd restart`

[4] Now find the hostname of your linux machine by running this command: `hostname`

[5] Now go to your Win10 machine, open File Explorer, and in the path bar enter: `\\hostname.local`

*Change "hostname" to the name you found in step [4] and don't forget to add the .local at the end.*

It should show you a print share which you can't do anything with and your Public share.

You can "pin" the \hostname.local location to your Start menu or to your "Quick Access" list so you don't have to go through this again.

Comment: Thank you Morbius1. That solved the problem quite effectively. The part I was missing was the "\\hostname.local" on the Windows side, partly because "hostname" was not showing up under the Network browser, which was throwing me off a bit. Please let me know if there's any way I can help boost your reputation, and thank you again for the very effective explanation. +1